# Checking result of a definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have:
$$\int_0^1 x \sqrt{x+2}dx$$
I apply substituion:
$u=\sqrt{x+2} $ , so $x=u^2-2  $ and $dx=2u du$
$$$$
Setting new limits: 
$ x=1,u=\sqrt{3}  $ and $x=0,u=\sqrt{2}$
$$$$
Replacing:
$$\int_\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{3}2u^4-4u^2 du$$
$$\frac{2}{5}u^5-\frac{4}{3}u^3$$

My final result is:
$$\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{x+2}^5-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{x+2}^3$$

But when iput the limits values , my final result is:
$$1.14-0.20=0.96$$
And checking on wolfram and geogebra i should have $0.82$, where is the error? I checked all several times

Answer (score 2):

Why do you substitute $u$ by $\sqrt{x+2}$ again once you got to
$\left[ \frac{2}{5}u^5 - \frac{4}{3}u^3 \right]_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{3}}$?

The latter quantity is equal to

$$\frac{2}{5}\left(\sqrt{3}^5 - \sqrt{2}^5\right) - \frac{4}{3}\left(\sqrt{3}^3 - \sqrt{2}^3\right) \approx 0.82$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you had already changed the limits to match the new variable $u$, why go back to $x$? You simply want

$$\left[\frac25u^5-\frac43u^3\right]_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt3}\;,$$

which to the nearest $0.01$ is indeed $0.82$. Specifically, it’s

$$\left(\frac25\cdot9\sqrt3-\frac43\cdot3\sqrt3\right)-\left(\frac25\cdot4\sqrt2-\frac43\cdot2\sqrt2\right)\;.$$

Note that the substitution $u=x+2$ works equally well: you get

$$\begin{align*}
\int_2^3(u-2)u^{1/2}du&=\int_2^3\left(u^{3/2}-2u^{1/2}\right)du\\
&=\left[\frac25u^{5/2}-\frac43u^{3/2}\right]_2^3\;,
\end{align*}$$

resulting in essentially the same numerical calculation at the end.